# Protect a react component from event handlers not wrapped in a `useCallback`

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have a component that triggers an async operations on first render, which eventually calls an event handler for the parent.

```
const Component = (props) => {
  const [options, setOptions] = useState([])
  useEffect(() => {
    findOptions().then(options => {
      setOptions(options);
      props.onChange(options[0])
    })
  }, [onChange])
  return <Autocomplete 
    options={options} 
    value={props.value} 
    onChange={(e, v) => props.onChange(v)} 
  />
}
```

This is very simplified. The component is prefilled with addresses close to the user's location using reverse geocoding, and the first value is selected. The actual component uses a combination of "near locations", place search, and custom favorites, but we still want the closest location to be pre-selected.

To respect "single source of truth", the parent component holds the "truth", so the selection is communicated to the owner using an event, just as it would when the user selects a value.

However, if the parent component does not wrap the event handler in a `useCallback`, every rerender will trigger the reverse geocoding, as the `useEffect` dependency array gets updated.

My current solution is to use a `useRef`.

```
const Component = (props) => {
  const [options, setOptions] = useState([])
  const onChangeRef = useRef(props.onChange)
  onChangeRef.current = props.onChange
  useEffect(() => {
    findOptions().then(options => {
      setOptions(options);
      onChangeRef.current(options[0])
    })
  }, [onChangeRef])
  return <Autocomplete 
    options={options} 
    value={props.value} 
    onChange={(e, v) => props.onChange(v)} 
  />
}
```

This works, i.e. now the reverse geocode is only called on first render.

But I find this to be quite a hack. Can I enforce the parent component to always use a `useCallback`?

Or is there a better pattern to handle this?

TypeScript solutions are also welcome, e.g. if I can enforce it with the type system, though I would prefer the stability of the code to not depend on typescript.

(originally, it was actually the parent component that handled reverse geocoding, along with the initially selected value. However, this was used two different places, so it was moved *into* this component to eliminate duplication)

Comment: All of this seems to really be trying to avoid using React state idiomatically at great cost. The parent component should really do the fetching as well.

Answer (score 2):

> To respect "single source of truth", the parent component holds the "truth",

If the parent component held the "truth", it will also hold the options, and, when fetched, the parent component would set them in its state (same as a child component calling `onChange`).

> (originally, it was actually the parent component that handled reverse geocoding, along with the initially selected value. However, this was used two different places, so it was moved into this component to eliminate duplication)

This desire to keep things DRY appears to have caused other complications? Just duplicate yourself and prefer duplicated clear code as opposed to DRY complicated code.

You probably can still DRY it out by using a custom hook used by the parent component (but being DRY is overrated in some circumstances).

I originally added a comment that said this seems like a valid case for `eslint-disable`. Your `onChangeRef` solution will behave the exact same as `eslint-disable rules-of-hooks` - except the latter will have less abstraction (no ref). So that's also an option - but it's still much less clear than just having the parent fetch the options.

Clarity >>> DRY